# DJANGO REST FRAMEWORK How to log in using username or email

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to configure the settings.py so that it is possible to log in using username or email

```
#Login con correo
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
#Following is added to enable registration with email instead of username
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `allauth` it's just a matter of setting `ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD` to `username_email`. You should take a look at their [docs](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html).